# arrange number with 5 digits from the biggest to lowest in c only with 'if'

Tags: c

I have a question. 
I working in c and I need to take a number from the user with 5 digits and sort it from the biggest number to the lowest  only with 'if'
I tried to do with 5 variables but the code getting huge.
there some easy way to do it only with 'ifs'???

for example, I get the number: 87953
the output should be : 98753.

(in the pic it only one situation).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0740b.jpg)

Comment: Is there a language where you can write programs only with `ifs`? It is certainly not c.

Comment: Show your code and what do you mean by "code getting huge"? Number of compare operations are more?

Comment: You could write a small Python program to generate your huge if-only C code.

Comment: this is the task from my teacher .... we just started to learn c...

Comment: Only 10 `if`s needed for a bubble sort, when the number is input as a string. Just approach it logically.

Comment: @WeatherVane how can I do it ? can you please explain me ?? plz

Comment: Compare `s[0]` with `s[1]` then with `s[2]` then with `s[3]` then with `s[4]` swapping where needed. Then compare `s[1]` with `s[2]` then with `s[3]` then with `s[4]` ditto. Then compare ... you get it? You just unroll the pair of loops you would otherwise use.

Comment: Are loops allowed in the solution to the exercise? Or only 'if' statements?

Comment: @WeatherVane You should really make that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Caleb OK I was reluctant because it is homework, so not a full program.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask, did you really found easier to post the link of an image of a photo of a screen displaying your code instead of copy-pasting the code into the question as text? There's probably something we should change in the help center, to better help the users. Or I'm just getting too old.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a `swap` function

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

First, a bubble sort **as a pair of loops** could be

```
char s[] = "87953";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
        if(s[i] > s[j]) {
            swap(s + i, s + j);
        }
    }
}

printf("%s\n", s);
```

Unrolling the loops, we only need 10 `if` statements:

```
char s[] = "87953";

if(s[0] > s[1])
    swap(s + 0, s + 1);
if(s[0] > s[2])
    swap(s + 0, s + 2);
if(s[0] > s[3])
    swap(s + 0, s + 3);
if(s[0] > s[4])
    swap(s + 0, s + 4);

if(s[1] > s[2])
    swap(s + 1, s + 2);
if(s[1] > s[3])
    swap(s + 1, s + 3);
if(s[1] > s[4])
    swap(s + 1, s + 4);

if(s[2] > s[3])
    swap(s + 2, s + 3);
if(s[2] > s[4])
    swap(s + 2, s + 4);

if(s[3] > s[4])
    swap(s + 3, s + 4);

printf("%s\n", s);
```

You could even move the comparisons into the `swap` function for more compact code, if you are allowed to use a function. If not, you'll have to expand it in-line anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For the case, that you also need it with some more digits (try 100):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NRDIGITS 5

int main(void) {
    printf("#include<stdio.h>\n\nint main(int argc, char **argv) {\n\tchar *s = argv[1];\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NRDIGITS-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < NRDIGITS; j++) 
            printf("\tif(s[%d]<s[%d]){s[%d]^=s[%d];s[%d]^=s[%d];s[%d]^=s[%d];}\n",
                                        j, j+1, j, j+1, j+1, j, j, j+1);
    printf("\tputs(s);\n}\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char values[10] = {0};
    scanf("%9s", values); // read input
    int nrOfCharacters = strlen(values);

    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfCharacters; i++) {

        for( int y = i + 1; y < nrOfCharacters; y++) {

            if((values[i] - '0') > (values[y] - '0')) {
                char tmp = values[y];
                values[y] = values[i];
                values[i] = tmp;
            }

        }
    }

    printf("output: %s", values);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive approach where number of `if`s are fixed irrespective size of array or number of digits,

```
#include <iostream>

int fun(char _arr[],int _size,int _index =0)
{
    if (_index+1 < _size)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (_arr[_index] < _arr[_index + 1])
        {
            std::swap(_arr[_index], _arr[_index + 1]);
            flag = true;
        }
        if (fun(_arr,  _size, _index + 1))
        {
            fun(_arr, _size, _index);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return flag;
        }
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    char a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5};

    for (auto _a : a)
    {
        std::cout << (int)_a << " ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    fun(a,sizeof(a),0);
    for (auto _a : a)
    {
        std::cout << (int)_a << " ";
    }
}
```

**output**:

> `1 2 3 4 5`
>   `5 4 3 2 1`